# Magento 2 API shows wrong stockid

Tags: rest, magento2, magento-2.3

I ran the Magento Rest API to get the stock id for a particular product but it's showing me wrong stock id.
We have three websites and each website has a separate stock, but when we call Magento API for these three websites, the stock is shown the same for every product which is wrong.

Please find below the result for the Magento RestAPI

```
GET https://stage.secure.kindsnacks.co.uk/rest/kind_uk_en/V1/products/KIN30137 HTTP/1.1
```

```json
{
  
    "stock_item": {
      "item_id": 1822,
      "product_id": 193,
      "stock_id": 1,
      "qty": 15,
      "is_in_stock": true,
      "is_qty_decimal": false,
      "show_default_notification_message": false,
      "use_config_min_qty": true,
      "min_qty": 1,
      "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
      "min_sale_qty": 1,
      "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
      "max_sale_qty": 10000,
      "use_config_backorders": true,
      "backorders": 0,
      "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
      "notify_stock_qty": 1,
      "use_config_qty_increments": true,
      "qty_increments": 0,
      "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
      "enable_qty_increments": false,
      "use_config_manage_stock": false,
      "manage_stock": true,
      "low_stock_date": null,
      "is_decimal_divided": false,
      "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get product stock status from here :
/V1/stockItems/:productSku